# PowerShell Import-Csv multiple CSV concatenation of columns

Tags: powershell, csv, multiple-columns

I would like to import multiple .csv files with 3 columns and 100 rows each, to a single .csv with each import going into the next 3 columns (ABC - DEF - GHI) rather than all concatenated into the first 3 columns with 1000s of rows.

I have tried `Import-Csv` but cannot control where the output is placed. Will I have to resort to using a COM object (`New-Object -ComObject excel.Application`) or is there a cleaner way to control which cells the import goes into?

Header lines are

```
PSComputerName,HotfixID,InstalledOn
```

But I need to have each loop to write across instead of underneath.

```
PSComputerName,HotfixID,InstalledOn,PSComputerName,HotfixID,InstalledOn,PSComputerName,HotfixID,InstalledOn
```

Comment: Very unclear. Import into what ? What is "import-csv" ? "control where the output is placed": what does that mean. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Apologies if unclear to you, but I did mention it in the first line. Using Powershell  "I would like to IMPORT MULTIPLE .CSV files with 3 columns and 100 rows each, TO A SINGLE .CSV " but I need each import spread across the columns.

Comment: Your question makes sense to me at least but you should specify (by editing your question) if your input files have header lines and how a header line would appear in the output.

Comment: No, you did not. You added Powershell in the title **after** my comment. Is much clearer now.

Comment: Sorry about that kebs, I assumed you would know something about programming languages and be able to recognize objects & syntax. Google is always a good start for things you don't understand :-)

Comment: @Johnny Basically every programming language you can think of (and then some) are being asked about on SO. It's not our job to guess which one you might be asking about. It's *your* job to clarify that.

Comment: Hey @Johnny boy, you are the one asking here, and telling people trying to help you what they should have done or know is certainly not the way to go over here. Especially when some claims of yours is false. BTW, you didn't even tag appropriately, I had to do your job, so please go get some humility.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not a typical use-case for CSVs, and `Import-Csv` (or `Export-Csv` for that matter) can't handle it at all. Both cmdlets convert the rows of a CSV to objects with properties named after the column headers or vice versa. Hence column headers MUST be unique if you want to use the `*-Csv` cmdlets.

The simplest approach to what you're trying to do would probably be something like this:

```
# read CSV data into distinct variables
$csv1 = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\1.csv'
$csv2 = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\2.csv'
$csv3 = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\3.csv'

# determine maximum number of rows
$max = $csv1.Count, $csv2.Count, $csv3.Count |
       Sort-Object
       Select-Object -Last 1

# concatenate corresponding rows from each file and write them to the output file
for ($i=0; $i -lt $csv1.Count; $i++) {
    # emulate missing rows in case the CSVs don't have the same number of rows
    $row1 = if ($csv1[$i]) {$csv1[$i]} else {',,'}
    $row2 = if ($csv2[$i]) {$csv2[$i]} else {',,'}
    $row3 = if ($csv3[$i]) {$csv3[$i]} else {',,'}

    "${row1},${row2},${row3}" | Add-Content 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
}
```

Comment: Excellent Ansgar, you are a legend among us mere mortals. It's exactly the explanation I needed and learned something new.